# Access Form displaying 2 or more unrelated tables

Tags: forms, ms-access

Dear fellow developers

I am trying to create an Access solution with forms that contain 2 or more data tables. The concept is that one table displays data from the system and the other table allows user input. The tables are not related to eachother, which I understand is a requirement for using forms and subforms.

Let me try to draw the design:

Table1

---

Field1  |  Field2 | Field3 |

---

Table 2

---

Field1 | Field 2 | Field3 |

---

Please help

Comment: Forms and subforms do not require that the tables are related. Relating the form and subform merely leverages the power.

Comment: I must have overlooked something then. Back to work! Thanks, Remou!